# Showing "waiting for emulator to start..." while running cordova-android App

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, android-emulator

I built simple cordova android app, for that I'm trying to run in my physical android mobile.. but it showing

No target specified and no devices found, deploying to emulator
No emulator specified, defaulting to VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone

Waiting for emulator to start...

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend **not** to use the built in Android emulators from Visual Studio. Instead, download the Android SDK Manager and then change your Visual Studio's ANDROID_HOME path to use it:

[image]

To download and update the Android SDK standalone refer to [Download System Images and create Android emulator](https://www.andreszsogon.com/using-android-8-and-9-emulators-without-android-studio/) in that page.

Notice that if using **VS2017**, your [Deploy to Emulator option will be gone](https://www.andreszsogon.com/visual-studio-2017-and-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/#android_home), but there are workarounds to keep deploying to emulator manually.